# WatiN has a bug in needed the window open to do successful screen capture

Tags: c#, .net, watin, automated-tests

I recently started a job with a company that is wanting me to make a .NET solution using WatiN that automates the capture of different screens on their website, and the problem I've been running into is getting black screen shots when I capture web page images if the browser is minimized or not visible.  Is there a way around this or a spot in the source code where I can "fix" the non rendering images of a minimized browser, or is this just a limitation I have to work with?

Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are running the watin tests with Internet Explorer? If so try adding the test site to IE's trusted sites list.

I generally use Nunit for Watin Integration test pass / fail detection. However, that aside, are you calling the `BringToFront` method prior to capturing the screen shot? EG:

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{

    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.State == TestState.Failure ||
        TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.State == TestState.Error)
    {
        Browser.BringToFront();
        Browser.CaptureWebPageToFile(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyHHmmss") + GetType().Name + ".png");
    }
    Browser.Close();
}
```

Comment: I am not calling BringToFront() as when I used that method it only gave focus to the minimized window.  I had to use ShowWindow() and supply it with the parameter to maximize it.  I was hoping to avoid having to have the browser open, but I guess it just may be a necessary part of how WatiN and automation testing works by using the rendering engine of the browser which doesn't render if the window is not visible.